# Generar un pago con tarjeta con el método mp.post(/v1/payments devuelve error 3031

Tags: .net, mercadopago

Estoy generando un pago, ya con un token desde .net utilizando el método  mp.post("/v1/payments" y me devuelve error:

> 3031 error: security_code_id can't be null.

No entiendo que parámetro debo pasarle, ya que en la docs de la api no existe el parámetro security_code_id
adjunto el código que le estoy enviando actualmente.

```
  payment = mp.post("/v1/payments", "{" +
                                   "\"transaction_amount\": " + monto + "," +
                                   "\"external_reference\": \"" + code + "\"," +
                                  "\"binary_mode\": true," +
                                   "\"token\": \"" + token + "\"," + 
                                   "\"description\": \"" + concepto + "\"," +
                                   "\"installments\": " + cuotas + "," +
                                   "\"payer\": {" + 
                                       "\"type\": \"customer\"," +
                                       "\"id\": \"" + codigoClienteMP + "\"" +
                                   "}" +
                               "}");
```

muchas gracias.

Answer (score 5):

Por si alguien le pasa, ya encontré el problema, hay que generar un token pasandole el codigo de seguridad.

```
Hashtable tokenTarjeta = mp.post("/v1/card_tokens/", "{\"public_key\": \"" + key + "\",\"cardId\": \"" + token + "\",\"securityCode\":\""+security+"\"}");
```

con el token que devuelve este evento, ahí llamar a la venta.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]!. Gracias por colaborar y aportar la solución a otros usuarios. Un saludo.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Recuerda que puedes marcar tu propia publicacion como respuesta aceptada en cuanto pasen 48h de la formulacion de la pregunta. Un saludo!